# Travis CI Showing Android Platform 28 error, but not mentioned anywhere in yml file

Tags: android, travis-ci, build-error

My Travis config only (as far as I understand) uses only API level 27 and build tools version `27.0.3`. But for some reason the Travis build fails, saying that the Android SDK **28** and build tools **28.0.3** licenses are not accepted. I never specified those versions in my `.travis.yml` file.

```
language: android
sudo: required
jdk: oraclejdk8

env:
  global:
  - ANDROID_API_LEVEL=27
  - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=27.0.3
  - ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - tools # appears twice as per Travis docs
    - build-tools-$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
    - android-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL
    - extra-android-m2repository
  licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-preview-license-52d11cd2'
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    - 'google-gdk-license-.+'

before_install:
  - touch $HOME/.android/repositories.cfg

before_cache:
  - rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock

cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
  - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
  - $HOME/.android/build-cache

before_script:
  - chmod +x gradlew

script:
  - ./gradlew clean build
  - ./gradlew test
```

The travis error is:

```
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

Is there a specific part that I should remove?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using the SDK's `sdk-manager` to install platforms and build-tools, instead of Travis's Android components. See the post at https://medium.com/@fawwazyusran/how-to-travis-ci-working-for-android-api-level-28-2fde7292813c for a complete tutorial.